# Oracle alter column if exists

Tags: oracle

Hello I've messed up a certain db migration. I'm more of a postgres person than oracle, and I googled for a while and haven't find a way to do something like `alter if exists`.

Basically what I need is to drop db columns if they exist, if they don't exist do nothing.

Example :

```
ALTER TABLE MY_PROPERTY_LOCK DROP COLUMN PROP
```

Fails if the `PROP` doesn't exist.

**Edit:**

Tried this, among other things :

```
declare p_count NUMBER;

select count(1) int p_count
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_PROPERTY_LOCK' 
and COLUMN_NAME = 'PROP';

IF p_count = 1 THEN
    ALTER TABLE MY_PROPERTY_LOCK DROP COLUMN PROP
END IF;
```

This is the error I get :

```
begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 3, column 21:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "P_COUNT" when expecting one of the following:

   , from into bulk
The symbol "," was substituted for "P_COUNT" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the data dictionary to check whether the column exists before trying to drop it

```
DECLARE
  l_cnt integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_cnt 
    FROM dba_tab_columns
   WHERE owner = <<table owner>>
     AND table_name = 'MY_PROPERTY_LOCK'
     AND column_name = 'PROP';

  IF( l_cnt = 1 )
  THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE my_property_lock DROP COLUMN prop';
  END IF;
END;
```

My bias, though, would be to record somewhere what version of the schema is installed and to determine what DDL to execute based on that.  For example, if you have a `VERSION` table that tells you that the current installed version is 1.4 and you want to drop the column when you move to version 1.5, you can just execute the `DROP` without worrying that it might not exist.

Comment: thanks it worked I had to change one bit though. instead of `dab_tab_columns` I've changed the table name to `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`

Comment: `dba_tab_columns` has data for every table in the database.  `all_tab_columns` has data for whatever tables the user you're logged in as has access to.  Every user has access to `all_tab_columns` (though each will see different data), not every user has access to `dba_tab_columns`.  I would expect, though, that a user that is installing an application would have full access to the data dictionary.